# what is the difference between a digital resistor and an analog resistor

Tags: led, resistors, pcb-design, simulation

I am using circuit simulation software a lot and I found that there are digital LEDs and analog LEDs and I couldn't find much information about them but their functions were self-explanatory to me. But how does a digital resistor differ from an analog resistor?

is this just a made-up addition that circuit simulation softwares have? i realized that in my particular application, I was using analog resistors everywhere mainly for dividing voltages. but then I had one 10k resistor (for limiting current) acting really weird. and when i switched it to digital, it was working properly. on the other hand, analog LEDs in my application work more similar to digital LEDs and their functions make more sense to me..

but that made me even more confused because i thought analog resistors and LEDs were the ones actually used in real life and digital counterparts are just an "ideal" form of them.

edit: here is the resistor. when it is analog, zero volts is across it, when it is digital, the correct amount of volts are cross it[image][image]

Comment: What circuit simulation program are you using?

Comment: I am using proteus

Comment: Digital ones are analog with digital selection like discrete values 1R 2R 4R or Pots with incremental or sliding controls like https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+resistor these

Comment: in the simulator's case though, can't you make the values whatever you want regardless if the resistor is digital or analog?

Comment: _"here is the resistor. when it is analog, zero volts is across it, when it is digital, the correct amount of volts are cross it"_ - but the correct amount of volts _is_ zero, so...

Comment: On my cell phone, I have clock app. In digital mode, it displays the time as a string of digits. For example: 18:07:42. In analog mode, it has a picture of a clock with minute hand and hour hand. I think it is like that. But I don't use proteus so I am not sure.

Comment: did i use Kirchoff's law incorrectly? i have 12 volts from the supply and it should have a voltage drop across the resistor right?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a digital resistor is a component whose value varies in discrete bumps. An analog resistor is the fundamental component which has a "certain" resistance value and which can vary continuously between two extremes under the influence of a voltage, for example. If no "influence variable" is present, it is a "fixed" resistance. This does not prevent the existence of influence quantities, temperature, among others. Simulators can also use virtual component, as long as a mathematical model is assigned to it. (google translate).

Use preferably digital models in digital simulation.
Use analog models in analog simulation.
If you make mixed simulation (analog components and digital components), some caution must be taken (interfaces needed, seen or hiden included).